# symfony2 hateoas - how to create entry point

Tags: rest, symfony, hateoas, fschateoasbundle

Can you tell me how to create entry point rest with [this Hateoas bundle](http://illdurand/BazingaHateoasBundle) for Symfony2?

I have searched with Google but I haven't find an answer

With old [bundle](https://github.com/TheFootballSocialClub/FSCHateoasBundle) we have used some services available from it (`fsc_hateoas.metadata.relation_builder.factory` and `fsc_hateoas.metadata.factory`).

Thank you for yours replies